# Group by clause which spans over multiple days based upon timestamp

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

Thanks for viewing my question.
I need help in writing a query which groups by content based upon date, however some content may be from previous date as the date is determined via a cut off time.

Following is an example of my problem

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tdata') is not null drop table #tdata;
go

create table #tdata(
  machine_id varchar(12),
  temestamp datetime,
  commit_count int,
  amount decimal(6,2)
);

insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-02 13:03:18.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-02 02:11:19.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-01 23:18:16.000',1,3.95;
*insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-01 22:45:20.000',1,3.95;*--from here and above should be in next date
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-01 10:13:06.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-01 01:13:59.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-01 00:26:51.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-01 00:17:01.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-01 00:13:11.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-01 00:06:15.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2017-12-31 22:59:59.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2017-12-31 21:27:25.000',1,3.95;
insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2017-12-31 20:32:22.000',1,3.95;

select machine_id, 
      cast(temestamp as date),
      sum(commit_count),
      sum(amount) 
from #tdata 
group by machine_id, cast(temestamp as date);
```

The above gives me following out put

```
machine_id  (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
Machine1    2017-12-31                         3    11.85
Machine1    2018-01-01                         8    31.60
Machine1    2018-01-02                         2    7.90
```

Where you can see the total for 2018-01-01 includes 2 `commit_count` from 2018-01-02 date as they occur in previous date but after cut off time . the totals should be 3,6 and 4...
Edit: Sometimes there will be data which will span the previous days cut off time and other times there won't be any data like that.Cut off time is 2200 hours or 10 pm
Can some one help write this query?

Comment: And what is the cut-off time?

Comment: Sorry, I did write it next to hour but I guess it wasn't clear
*insert into #tdata select 'Machine1','2018-01-01 22:45:20.000',1,3.95;*--from here and above should be in next date
Cut off time is 22 hour or 10 pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cut of the time for example at 22:00, you can actually solve this quite easily with a small "hack" - you can add 2 hours to the date first and then group by this new value:

```
DATEADD(hour, 2, temistamp)
```

This will make all values after 22:00 "overflow" to the next day, and you can just use the `cast` cut the time and group by this.

And just a small suggestion: there is a typo in the column name - it should be `timestamp` :-)

Comment: I wonder if this will work when there is no data which spans the 2 dates, meaning no data after the cut off date? I have edited my question to reflect this condition

Comment: Yes, it will still work as intended, because all the data that should belong to the given day will fall into it still after adding the 2 hour difference.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to figure out what exactly I needed to get done to get answer to my issue, however, it was your hack which guided me in the direction which eventually resulted in the right answer.